# OpenBB Terminal Installation error (for Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to run the below in Python.

```
from openbb_terminal.sdk import openbb
```

To do so, I would need to install `openBB`, However, I got the below error, and I don't know how to fix it ( I looked for hidden files but there is no) :

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/OpenBB Terminal/.OpenBB/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/liblzma.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/OpenBB Terminal/.OpenBB/libtiff.6.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libtiff.6.dylib requires version 10.0.0
```

Anyone would be able to help?

Looked for hidden files to remove `liblzma.5.dylib`.
but did see any

Comment: on Linux (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint) it would need to install `apt install liblzma5`. On Mac probably it may need to use `brew` to install it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
Does it necessarily mean I need to install Homebrew ? are there contraindications ?
Documentation says "Executable Python scripts will be in $(brew --prefix)/bin."

Comment: `liblzma5` is NOT python module but `C/C++` library and you can't install it with `pip` but you have to use tools like `brew` to install this library. I don't have Mac but maybe it use other tool to install libraries.